# HttpWebRequest POST in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

I have an Api that allows users to be inserted into the database. I am trying requesting the Api in a windows forms application but keep getting System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'I am relatively new to Api requests. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly, thanks.

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int StoreCustomerID { get; set; }
        // Actaul customer from store ID
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        //public User Credentials { get; set; }
        public string DeviceToken { get; set; }
        //public CustomerCard Details { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool IsError { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        //Public Property StoreNumber As Integer


            public string Token { get; set; }
            public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
            public string SecretKey { get; set; }

    }
```

ApiRequest class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Customer cust = new Customer();
            InsertUpdateCustomer(cust, "http://Example.com");
        }

        public static Customer InsertUpdateCustomer(Customer MyCustomer, string ServerAddress)
        {

            //Dim PostData As New CardInfo With {.CardNumber = CardNumber, .Reference = Reference, .SaleDate = DateTime.Now, .SaleTotalAmount = Amount, .StoreNumber = StoreNumber, .TransactionTypeID = Transaction}

            //Customer Res = new Customer();
            string webAddr = ServerAddress + "/api/Customer/Insert";


            WebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Giftworx-App", "Posworx");
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 4000;

            MyCustomer.Name = "Janice";
            MyCustomer.Surname = "Alexander";
            MyCustomer.Email = "j@example.com";
            MyCustomer.MobilePhone = "0314011828";
            MyCustomer.Gender = "Female";
            MyCustomer.DOB = DateTime.Now;
            MyCustomer.Token = "wMq0cZ4iN7uOnJdrSdYITQcWHQ9VYgiLCosN7Rj9MSdqmZKSTuHCb08jeO/wlp3bCoK/sbEwwvjlZUeQdj8p5w==";
            MyCustomer.SecretKey = "jdghe45";
            MyCustomer.Authenticated = true;


            try
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {

                    string jsonstring;


                    MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();

                    //Serialize the Record object to a memory stream using DataContractJsonSerializer.
                    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customer));
                    ser.WriteObject(stream1, MyCustomer);


                    stream1.Position = 0;

                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);

                    jsonstring = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    Debug.WriteLine("JSON form of Insert Loyaltyworx Update Customer object: ");
                    Debug.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(jsonstring));

                    streamWriter.Write(jsonstring);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(result));

                        Customer MyResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(result);


                        Debug.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(result));

                        return MyResult;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: When you debug the server side (the web server) what occurs prior to it returning the 401? Please include the source code of the (server side) method that it is invoking...

Comment: Thanks for responding, I realized I was just missing a non-nullable field. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data in to a json string  as below

```
 Customer cust = new Customer();
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cust );
 JObject json2 = JObject.Parse(json);
```

and then you can make a call like this.

```
 string webAddr = ServerAddress + "/api/Customer/Insert";
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(webAddr , json2).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I was just missing a non-nullable field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are lunching your app as administrator and check that the firewall/antivirus is not blocking.